# My API is working with Chrome, but not with anything else

Tags: ssl, curl

I am having a weird issue. I have an API on an internal server that I'm trying to communicate with. If I put the URL in Chrome, it works fine (although I do get an SSL error that I have to ignore) and it returns the XML I need. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Chrome Browser works]

Now if I try to use cURL or Postman or any other program to try and hit it, I get an SSL error. Now the SSL cert is invalid on the server, so that makes sense. However, I am using the `-k` switch on cURL to ignore the certificate errors and in Postman, I have unchecked the `Check for valid SSL Certificate`. However, I can't pull this XML up in any other application, except Chrome. Here is a screenshot of cURL:

[image]

Any ideas on why this works fine on the browser but not with cURL or Postman or any other app? (also tried SoapUI and Fiddler)

Comment: Support for TLS protocol versions, ciphers and features differs between TLS stacks and configurations. Chrome is using BoringSSL as backend. Your server might simply be configured too strict regarding protocol version and ciphers so that some clients will not be able to connect. But this is mainly speculation because nothing is known about your actual server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I don't know much about the server because it's a work server, but I know it uses TLS 1.2. And also, I should clarify. When I say Chrome, I mean web browsers in general because it is also working for IE 11.0.

Comment: Could it be that the server requires a client certificate which is installed for Chrome and IE but which you don't supply to curl and postman?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Possibly

Comment: The type of encryption it uses is: `tls_rsa_with_3des_ede_cbc_sha`

Comment: Hm, this is a pretty old cipher which is now considered weak and disabled in several implementations by default. Browsers still tend to support it since there are some old and broken servers out there but other applications do not.  This might be the problem or it might be a missing client certificate.